# Simple_form_for limiting datetime choices in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, simple-form-for

I am trying to set a datetime field using simple_form_for in Rails so that it limits the choices to starting from 7 days from today's date.

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@offer) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :examdatetime, label: 'Please enter date:',  
        :start_year => Time.new.year, 
        :start_month => Time.new.month, 
        :start_day => Time.new.day+7 %>
 <% end %>
```

It works for the year but not for the date and month.  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there are `start_month` and `start_day` options available to the date field ?

Comment: No, I'm not.  i know the :start_year option works so i was trying the others.

Comment: I haven't seen `start_month` and `start_day` options being used and I can't find them in any documentation, therefore that could be the source of your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer:

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@offer) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :examdatetime, label: 'Please enter date:',  
      :start_year => Time.new.year, 
      default: 7.days.from_now  %>
 <% end %>
```

seems to do the trick!